# Rel: le_antisymmetric comprehension

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

Rel chapter from Logical foundations. I was given a solution to the excersize that I'm trying to comprehend:

```
Definition antisymmetric {X: Type} (R: relation X) :=
  forall a b : X, (R a b) -> (R b a) -> a = b.

Theorem le_antisymmetric :
  antisymmetric le.
Proof.
  unfold antisymmetric. intros a b [| b' H1] H2.
  - reflexivity.
  - absurd (S b' <= b').
    + apply le_Sn_n.
    + etransitivity ; eassumption.
```

I don't understand, how does intro pattern `[| b' H1]` work? After intros it shows:

```
2 subgoals (ID 43)

  a, b : nat
  H2 : a <= a
  ============================
  a = a

subgoal 2 (ID 46) is:
 a = S b'
```

2-nd subgoal:

```
a, b, b' : nat
H1 : a <= b'
H2 : S b' <= a
============================
a = S b'
```

I understand that it is equivalent to destruct, but what sort of destruct? It's definitely not a simple `destruct b`.

Also I'm trying to understand the logics behind using `absurd (S b' <= b')` tactics. Does it mean that if we prove that `a = S b'` in this context, it would imply that after we rewrite `a` to `S b'` in H1, we get: `S b' <= b'`, which is a universally false statement (absurd)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intros a b [| b' H1] H2` is equivalent to

```
intros a b H H2.
destruct H as [| b' H1].
```

`destruct` patterns generally follow the rules that if an inductive type has a single constructor (e.g. products) then for `x` in that inductive type, `destruct x as [a b c...]` does (non-recursive) induction and renames the new variables to `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. When the inductive type has more than one constructor, there are multiple cases. For that, you use `destruct x as [a b c ... | d e f ... | ...]`. These destruction patterns can be nested if needed, e.g. `destruct x as [[a b] | [c [d | e]]]`. Note that if a constructor takes no arguments, there is nothing to rename, so you can leave the pattern empty.

In particular, something like a natural number can be destructed with `destruct n as [ | n']`. This divides into the cases where `n` is zero (and the constructor has no arguments, so there's nothing to the left of the `|`) or `n` is the successor of `n'`. Similarly, a list could be destructed as `destruct li as [ | a li']` to divide into the cases where the list is `nil` and where it is `cons a li'`. The space to the left of the `|` is unnecessary, so you could do `destruct li as [| a li']`.

What's happening in your case specifically is that `le` is defined as an inductive type something along the lines of

```
Inductive le (n : nat) : nat -> Prop :=
| le_n : le n n
| le_S : forall m : nat, le n m -> le n (S m).
```

So there are two cases: one with no arguments, and the successor case where the arguments are `m: nat` and `H: le n m`. Hence, the destruct pattern is `[| m H]`.

---

To answer your second question, `absurd (S b' <= b').` means that (we think) we're able to prove `S b' <= b'` in the current context. We can also prove (in the same context) that `S b' <= b'` is absurd, i.e. leads to a witness of `False` (more precisely, `S b' <= b' -> False`). Using the induction principle for `False`, this allows us to generate a witness for any type, and in particular for `a = S b'`.

You can see what kind of proof term `absurd` produces with a minimal experiment.

```
Goal forall A B: Type, A.
Proof.
  intros A B.
  absurd B.
  Show Proof.
```

This should print `(fun A B : Type => False_rect A (?Goal ?Goal0))`. The first goal (`?Goal`) has type `~B` (i.e. `B -> False`). The second goal (`?Goal0`) has type `B`. If we can provide both, then `?Goal ?Goal0` has type `False`, so `False_rect A (?Goal ?Goal0)` produces a witness of type `A`.